# After ProGuard,the application will crash, help to understand what is the reason?

Tags: android

I'm doing my application, I am using retrofit, rxJava, retrofit: converter-gson.Ya decided to protect your application using ProGuard, I copied all of proguard-android.txt in proguard-rules.pro, created and signed application received error:

```
 Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Warning:there were 67 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscUnboundedArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpscLinkedQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentSequencedCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
Warning:retrofit.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

If I just use **-dontwarn**, the application will crash with an error:

```
02-22 19:38:16.998 31147-31147/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 31147
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.myapplication.b.c.c()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.myapplication.c.b$b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.example.myapplication.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.b(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$n.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$n.c(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.J(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.k(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16653)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2198)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                at android.app.ActivityTh
```

ProGuard:

```
    # This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Understand the @Keep support annotation.
-keep class android.support.annotation.Keep

-keep @android.support.annotation.Keep class * {*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep <init>(...);
}
```

My Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Help me please!

**SOLVED**
I have everything worked out, I added snippets (https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets): retrofit, rxjava, okio, picasso, support-v7-appcompat, butterknife-7. I added proguard-rules.pro:

```
    ## --------------- Start Project specifics --------------- ##

-keep class com.example.yourapp.model.Yourmodel{ *; }
-keep class com.example.yourapp.model.Yourmodel{ *; }
-keep class com.example.yourapp.model.Yourmodel{ *; }



# Keep the BuildConfig
-keep class com.example.BuildConfig { *; }

# Keep the support library
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
# or have been blown up by ProGuard in the past

## ---------------- End Project specifics ---------------- ##
```

**And my Gradle looks like this:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'proguard-rx-java.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-square-retrofit.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-square-picasso.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-square-okio.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-butterknife-7.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-support-v7-appcompat.pro'
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Add your full code...

Comment: This is a very big project, I can not put the code

Comment: your problem is here `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.myapplication.b.c.c()' on a null object reference` if you have any String method that pointing to a null object.

Comment: but without proguard, I do not get this error

Comment: The problem is you are `changing` some needed classes with Proguard, it is hard to tell which ones without seeing the code, the dependency libraries, etc. I would look the libraries/classes mentioned in the ProGuard stack trace and try to keep them as you are doing with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your proguard rules:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Try also updating your ProGuard rules based on this https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets as this might not be enough. In general you should check if the libraries you're using do not have any specific ProGuard rules that need to be included :/

Comment: I included snippets Retrofit and rxJava, but it does not work, I still get the error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.myapplication.b.c.c()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Have you added this: https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-okio.pro ?

Comment: Yes, your decision helped me, I had to keep the model

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

-dontnote retrofit2.Platform

-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor

-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes Exceptions